# pgfplot x tick not displaying percent symbol

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to change plain value displayed beside a bar to percentage, but this didn't work:

```
% change to percentage
\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    nodes near coords align=horizontal,
        xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        visualization depends on={x \as \originalvalue}
    }
}
```

And main documentation:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    ytick=\empty,
    y=0.5cm, enlarge y limits={true, abs value=0.75},
    enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.15},
    xlabel=,
    ylabel=,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels={,},
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal,
    percentage plot
]
    \addplot [draw opacity=0, fill=verylightgrey, discard if={num}{1}] table [x=value, y=num] {risk.dat};
    \addplot [draw opacity=0, fill=lightred, discard if not={num}{1}] table [x=value, y=num, y expr=\coordindex] {risk.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is (in red is what I want):

[image]

Comment: `nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta \%}`

Comment: @percusse `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/node near coords*'`

Comment: I've edited my comment please check again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify what `pgfplots` should write via `nodes near coords*` key with custom code. For your case, adding a percent sign can be done via

```
nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta \%}
```

See the manual for more details.